# Why GWT Linker Cross-Site-Iframe Ignoring the script tags in the gwt.xml?

Tags: java, xml, gwt, iframe

Why **gwt-recaptcha-1.0.0.Beta2.jar** blocks script tags in recaptcha jar while linking modules?

In my web application using GWT, I am using captcha verification. For using captcha I used `Claudius Hauptmann's gwt-recaptcha-1.0.0.Beta2.jar`. In the gwt.xml file of this jar there is a script configuration as follows:

```
<module>
        <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User"/>
        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"/>
</module>
```

When I run the project it ignores loading the scripts by giving these messages in console:

```
Linking modules
   Bootstrap link for command-line module 'com.web.Ask'
      Linking module 'ask'
         Invoking Linker Cross-Site-Iframe
            Ignoring the following script tags in the gwt.xml file
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js
raphael.js
```

I would like to know what is the exact reason  for ignoring these file. How to resolve it.

**PS**: before some days it was working perfectly and after some config changes it stopped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure about this fix,

please try

Remove  linker elements from  your GWT module XML like

```
<add-linker name="xsiframe" />
<set-configuration-property name='xsiframe.failIfScriptTag' value='FALSE' />
```